# Delete character on button click unless the input value is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Presently I am using the following code to delete a character from an input display:

```
function deleteChar(input) {
  input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1)
}
```

Unfortunately, if the display reads just one character, this function when activated on button click will leave the input display blank. I would like for it to return 0 in such circumstances. I have tried targeting the string length, but I have not been successful. How can I amend this function to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Or is it just me not getting what he's aiming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function deleteChar(input) {
    if(input.value.length == 1) {
        input.value = 0;
    } else {
        input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="123" id="inputElement" />
<button onclick="deleteChar(document.getElementById('inputElement'))">Click</button>
```

If you want a shorter version, feel free to use this (which includes a ternary operator):

```
function deleteChar(input) {
    input.value = input.value.length == 1 ? 0 : input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it.

Comment: @newbie2015 No problemo! Feel free to mark it as the correct answer when you can :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
function deleteChar(input) {
    if(input.value.length == 1) return 0;         //return 0 if there is only 1 character
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the ternary operator for this:

```
function deleteChar(input) {
    input.value = input.value.length === 1 
      ? 0 
      : input.value.substr( 0, input.value.length - 1 )
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose another ternary version

```
function deleteChar(input) {
  nV = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - 1);
  input.value = nV ? nV : 0;
}
```

Code explanation:

1. assign the new value to the variable `nV`
2. assigns the `input.value` based on the ternary operator

This assignment is equivalent to the following:

```
if (nV) {
  input.value = nV;
} else {
  input.value = 0;
}
```